# sql inject in sqlmap what can i do for this

Tags: sqlmap

I have a problem with this piece of code ate and had a few with me please help, what can i do for this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/087LT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use mysql_real_escape_string function when you are getting some inputs from user

Comment: This problem was solved with the help of Tampere in sqlmap